# What is the difference between spring starters and other spring packages?

Tags: spring-boot

There are a variety of spring starter packages what is the difference between a package such as spring-boot-starter-security and spring-security-web.

I feel as though spring-boot-starter-security would be a collection of several packages that would assist in creating a secure application. If so is there anyway to see what these starters of composed of?